# How to check if Mouse is available in XNA - Monogame

Tags: c#, xna, mouse, monogame, win-universal-app

I'm using Monogame to develop an universal app for Windows Store and Windows Phone.

I know that is possible to check if a TouchPanel is available and I'm looking for a method that do the same thing with a mouse.

I can't ignore the fact that a mouse is not connected because instructions like this.IsMouseVisible = true; launch exceptions on Windows Phone.

Thank you all for your reply,

Luca.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have various solutions, depends of what you want to do :

1. You can add a try-catch around `this.IsMouseVisible`. If you get a exception, you know for sure that the mouse is unavailable.
2. You have conditional compilation symbols with XNA. Use `#if !WINDOWS_PHONE` to prevent phones to check the mouse. I think you can consider that most of phones don't use mouse. (See [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd282469.aspx))